# Eloqua Dynamic Content is not working on Outlook when using inside MSO code

Tags: html, oracle, outlook, html-email, eloqua

On Eloqua, I have tried to put a dynamic content inside MSO code for outlook. But that dynamic content block is not showing on outlook platform.

This is working on Gmail and other platforms.

Only not working on outlook (<!--[if mso]>)

Code:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<span elqid="12345" elqtype="DynamicContent" class="remove-absolute" style="display: block"></span>
<![endif]-->  
                                          
<!--[if !mso]> -->
<span elqid="12345" elqtype="DynamicContent" class="remove-absolute" style="display: block"></span>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Can you see what the final output is? (If you get your email, forward it to yourself, and then 'view source', what's the code there?)